# Matching case insenstive phrase from string

Tags: java, regex, string

My job is to traverse a tree and add html tags around the target word with the following contstraints:

> A taggable word is a sequence of alphabetic letters that is not a part
>   of another word, and may have one of the following punctuations AS THE
>   LAST CHARACTER: period '.', comma ',', question mark '?', exclamation
>   point '!', colon ':' and semicolon ';'.
>
> Note that the taggable word may be embedded within a longer piece of
>   text (such as tagging "quick" in the "The quick brown fox"), and may
>   occur multiple times in the containing text.
>
> As another example, if you were asked to add a bold tag around "cow",
>   you would tag the entire word, along with last character punctuation,
>   in the following cases: "cow", "cow!", "cow?", "cow.", "cow;", "cow:",
>   "COW", "cOw". That is you would have "cow", "cow!", "cow?", "cow.",
>   "cow:", "cow;", "COW", "cOw" (the last two are case insensitive
>   matches).
>
> But you would NOT tag "cow" in these words: "cows", "cowabunga" (in
>   both cases, not a word by itself, but part of a bigger word), "?cows",
>   (not just letters, punctuation not last character) "cow?!!", (only one
>   punctuation character at the end is acceptable), "cow's" (apostrophe
>   is not a letter).

traversing the tree is no problem, but I am having trouble coming up with a block that will determine where the proper place to add the tags are:

```
private void inorderAdd(TagNode root, String tag){
      if (root == null){
          return;
      }

      //Test if the tag is in the string at all
      if(root.tag.contains(tag)){
          String text = root.tag;
          String[] pieces =  text.split(" ");

          //check each array item for the target sequence
          for(int i = 0; i < pieces.length-1; i++){ 
              if(pieces[i].contains(tag)){

              }
          }
      }

      inorderAdd(root.firstChild, tag);
      inorderAdd(root.sibling, tag);
```

}

At this point I have the phrase that I know contains the tag split into an array with each word separated. I'm not sure where to go from here, as I need to consider case at some point as well as having a number of punctuation characters as well.

Comment: This site should not be regarded as a code generator tool.

Comment: that's not what I'm looking for, is there some way to avoid numerous if statements for each punctuation mark, or case variant of the tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at Pattern

Something like:

```
Pattern reg = Pattern.compile( "\\b(" + tag + "[!.:?]?)\\b", Pattern. CASE_INSENSITIVE)
```

Then you should be able to check the condition like this:

```
Matcher m = reg.matcher(text)
    ...
if (m.matches()) //true if found a match

m.start(1) / m.end(1) //get the exact location of matched word
```